# List of files installed by Nuget

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have installed a JS library package using Nuget in Visual studio.
Now I would like to know what are JS and CSS files that got created in my VS project.

How can I get list of files installed by Nuget in Visual studio for a given package?

I have checked "packages.config" , it does not provide any information regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files added into the project will be the files inside the **Content** directory inside the NuGet package (.nupkg).

However a NuGet package could add files using PowerShell script so those would need to be checked manually as well, if any exist.